# Is there a way to get the React / Redux's bundle.js on the local hard drive?

Tags: reactjs, redux

When the Reach / Redux app is finally running, there is a file `bindle.js`, but if I use

```
find . -name '*bundle.js*' | xargs ls -l
```

all the `bundle.js` files in the repo are not the one that was just built (meaning, those are older files and do not have a current timestamp if I just edited my project 10 seconds ago).

Is the only way to get this file from http://localhost:8080/bundle.js ? This file should have been made and sit inside the hard drive, and I think the server doesn't make it every time when the browser requests it.

Answer (score 2):

webpack-dev-server and similar only create the bundles in memory for performance reasons. You can do single builds with the `webpack` command.

Comment: I am new to React / Redux. Mind giving what command line to use to have `webpack` build it?

Comment: You should be able to just enter the command "webpack" from the directory your webpack config file is in to build your bundle.js file.

Answer (score 0):

One more option if you are using a more recent version of React:

I found that the latest React, it will tell you to use

```
create-react-app hello-world
```

to create the app, and then there is an official

```
npm run build
```

to build it to host it as a Gthub page, or on your own website.  The `bundle.js` will then be inside the `build/static/js` directory. (with a different filename such as `main.54f24123.js` that seems to be used for busting the cache).